# Access property json in variable (flowVars) Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

i have a problem like this: I saved my request Json to Variable and now i want to access property in Json throught Variable. How can i do this ? #[flowVars.x.id] or #[flowVars.x/id] not working. And i using open source so i can't use datawave too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a Java object before assigning to the flowVar:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.lang.Object"/>
```

Then you can access the attributes by name.

Comment: Thanks a lots. Is this the only way?

Comment: I think there are other alternatives.